# Time affecting price elasticity of supply

Tags: elasticity

I'm given to understand that the supply of any product at one moment is fixed regardless of the price but on the long run the firm could produce more of the product and so the supply become more price elastic. Ehat I'm asking is how come when we draw a supply curve and an increase in price has occured wich means and extension in the supply curve and the quantity is increased , how come the curve didn't flatten (because it became more more price elastic) how come it extended ?!